# Is there any way to remove a commit from somewhere along your current HEAD's history in git?

Tags: git

Without `git rebase -i HEAD~(1+whatever the depth of the commit is)`? e.g. something like `git drop iu34kjh233`

I work on a more cvs-like workflow (and I don't have the say to change that) so we land one commit cherry-picked on top of `master` at a time. Sometimes I'll be working on two things with `HEAD` as the base and `commit1` on top of `HEAD` and `commit2` on top of `commit1`. It would be convenient to be able to just `git drop commit1 && git push -f mygithubrepo HEAD:refs/heads/myprbranch` when I want to PR `commit2`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a rebase?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any clean way of doing this without `git rebase`

If you dont mind dirty history, you can still `git revert <commit_sha>` that will create inverted commit to the one you want to drop.

Dont forget that `rebase` is a very universal and powerfull tool, tricky to use too.

Mostley by the fact that if you remove one commit from the midlle of the history, you will create new history flow, with commit sha-s totaly different from what they originaly were. Doing any automatic/scripted work around this is dangerous. Especialy when the branch is alredy pushed to remote.